# Issue while initiating the constructor for collection

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, jasper-reports

I have an arrayList (`List dinTabel = new ArrayList();`) which I want to pass to JasperReport in a collection (`Collection<ExtraContList> coll = new ArrayList<ExtraContList>();`)

I have my ExtraContList java class here:

```
package banking.model;

import java.util.List;

public class ExtraContList {

    private List<String> cont;
    private List<String> sum_deb;
    private List<String> sum_cred;
    private List<String> sold_curent;
    private List<String> data;

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Integer getCont() {
        return cont;
    }

    public List<String> getSum_deb() {
        return sum_deb;
    }

    public List<String> getSum_cred() {
        return sum_cred;
    }

    public List<String> getSold_curent() {
        return sold_curent;
    }



    public ExtraContList(List<String> data, List<String> sum_deb, List<String> sum_cred,
            List<String> sold_curent, Integer cont) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.cont = cont;
        this.sum_deb = sum_deb;
        this.sum_cred = sum_cred;
        this.sold_curent = sold_curent;
    }


}
```

But whenever I try to add the arrayList by this line

```
coll.add(new ExtraContList(Arrays.asList(resultSet.getString("d_o"),ConturiUserID,resultSet.getString("tsum")," ",resultSet.getString("sCS"))));
```

it tells me that the Constructor is undefined, and it creates me this

```
public ExtraContList(List<? extends Object> asList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Would you kindly tell me..how to add this

```
public ExtraContList(List<String> data, List<String> sum_deb, List<String> sum_cred,
                List<String> sold_curent, Integer cont) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.cont = cont;
            this.sum_deb = sum_deb;
            this.sum_cred = sum_cred;
            this.sold_curent = sold_curent;
        }
```

to the constructor (`ExtraContList(List<? extends Object> asList)`)?

UPDATE:
I changed from coll.add(new `ExtraContList(Arrays.asList(resultSet.getString("d_o"),ConturiUserID," ",resultSet.getString("tsum"),resultSet.getString("sCD"))));`

to

```
coll.add(new ExtraContList(Arrays.asList(resultSet.getString("d_o")),Arrays.asList(ConturiUserIDint),Arrays.asList(" "),Arrays.asList(resultSet.getString("tsum")),Arrays.asList(resultSet.getString("sCD"))));
```

I can't figure out how to print the content of my collection coll, to see if everyting is fine. After running

```
System.out.println(coll);
```

it prints me

```
[banking.model.ExtraContList@4593f370, banking.model.ExtraContList@23feaea9, banking.model.ExtraContList@221b98b5]
```

I added those fields in my jrxml:

```
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="data" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="sold_curent" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="sum_cred" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="class" class="java.lang.Class"/>
    <field name="sum_deb" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="cont" class="java.util.List"/>
```

But I receive this:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: data.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:205)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:170)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:104)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1501)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1402)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1378)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:108)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:615)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:432)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:162)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:145)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:689)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1005)
    at banking.web.servlets.ExtraCont.doPost(ExtraCont.java:321)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'data' on class 'class java.lang.String'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1269)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:808)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:884)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:464)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:185)
    ... 35 more
```

I still get the error even after I changed the field names from

```
<field name="data" class="java.util.List"/>
```

into:

```
<field name="data" class="banking.model.ExtraContList"/>
```

I also modified the cont variabile from Integer to List

Comment: there is no constructor with single argument `List` in `ExtraContList` class

Comment: *it creates me this*: no it doesn't. You chose to let it create this constructor, without trying to understand if it was somethign desirable or not. The problem is that the constructor of `extraContList` (which should be renamed, at least to restec the Java naming conventions), expects 4 lists and an integer. And you're trying to call it with only one list. So something is clearly incorrect. You need to think about what you're doing: if a plane needs two wings, wheels, a cabin and a cockpit to be correctly built, you can't just pass wheels.

Comment: Seems like you expect the code to automatically retrieve all rows from the `ResultSet`, without you writing a loop. Why would you expect that? That isn't what `Arrays.asList` does. --- Create the 4 lists, do a loop with `while (resultSet.next()) { ... }`, and add the values to the lists. --- Better yet, create a class with 4 fields, then make a single list of those objects.

Comment: And please read about java naming conventions. You are violating them all over the place, which makes it really hard and unpleasant to look at your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReport iReport: JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039325/jasperreport-ireport-jrexception-error-retrieving-field-value-from-bean)